# Going through multiple XML files to find a specific value

Tags: go

I'm trying to find a solution where I can search through 1189 XML files to find a specific value that a user provides.

As an example, the user is looking for a postal code, 8913CK, which can be found in any of the 1189 XML files. What would be the best way to approach this? I've tried looping through the files, which results in slow and inefficient responses and have tried setting up channels and workers which made the results a lot quicker, but still not desirable and sometimes no results showed up at all (this might be because I'm not as familiar with GoLang).

The struct of the XML file is as follows:

```
type NumPostal struct {
    BagObject struct {
        Nummeraanduiding struct {
            Identificatie struct {
                Text   string `xml:",chardata"`
                Domein string `xml:"domein,attr"`
            } `xml:"identificatie"`
            Huisnummer struct {
                Text string `xml:",chardata"`
            } `xml:"huisnummer"`
            Huisletter struct {
                Text string `xml:",chardata"`
            } `xml:"huisletter"`
            Postcode struct {
                Text string `xml:",chardata"`
            } `xml:"postcode"`
            LigtAan struct {
                OpenbareRuimteRef struct {
                    Text   string `xml:",chardata"`
                } `xml:"OpenbareRuimteRef"`
            } `xml:"ligtAan"`
            Huisnummertoevoeging struct {
                Text string `xml:",chardata"`
            } `xml:"huisnummertoevoeging"`
        } `xml:"Nummeraanduiding"`
    } `xml:"bagObject"`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Effectively querying the BAG files directly isn't doable in a reasonable time due to the amount of unindexed data. I recommend setting up [BAG-Extract](https://docs.nlextract.nl/en/latest/bagextract.html), an existing project which allows you to import the BAG dataset into a postgres database which you can then query.

Comment: Sounds good! I'll give this a shot